# Char array from C to ASM x64 GAS

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, char, 64-bit

I've got assessment to use array from C in ASM function.
Figured out that I need to pass address to that array. But how after that access values of array in ASM? (f.e. array[0], array[1] etc.)

C function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void asm_function(char *address);

int main() {

char array[] = "Abc";
asm_function(15, array);
return 0;

}
```

ASM function:

```
 .type asm_function, @function

 .section .data

 EXIT = 60
 EXIT_SUCCESS = 1
 BUFF_LENGTH = 512

 format: .asciz "%s\n"

 .section .bss
 .lcomm buffer, BUFF_LENGTH


 .section .text
 .globl asm_function

 asm_function:

 movq %rdi, buffer

 subq $8, %rsp
 movq $0, %rax
 movq buffer_lancuch, %rsi
 movq $format, %rdi
 call printf       #prints whole String


 exit:
 addq $8, %rsp
 movq $EXIT, %rax
 movq $EXIT_SUCCESS, %rdi
 syscall
```

What I acctually need is to access all of the chars seperately.
Will appreciate all of hints.

Comment: What do you need to do with each character?

Comment: Function takes one more argument (number) which is 'rotation'. To each of char's I need to add this 'rotation'. It's Caesar cipher (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: You got the base address, the elements come one after another consecutively from that address. You just need to add the index of the item. Incidentally this is exactly the same as in C. Remember `a[b]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(a+b)`.